# fast querying items restored from the bin

Tags: sitecore-query

I deleted an item located at `/sitecore/content/foo/bar` with several subitems from Sitecore and restored it back from Recycle Bin immediately.

Now I'm able to see all the subitems if I run a query in XPath Builder like this: `fast:/sitecore/content/foo/bar/*`, but nothing if it's like this:
`fast:/sitecore/content/foo/bar//*`. The exact same query (with `//*`) works at an another server where the same application is deployed but nothing was deleted&restored.

If I run `fast:/sitecore/content/foo//*` I get everything `foo` contains except for `bar` and its subitems.

In attempt to troubleshoot I tried restarting the iis application pool, sql service and pretty much everything I could lay my hands at in case something got cashed. Would really appreciate a bit of advice on handling this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open Sitecore.config and increase the `DefaultSQLTimeout` setting to 2 hours (just in case).
2. Go to the Control Panel and run the "Clean up Databases" application for the Master and Web databases. Don't close the dialog until the cleanup is done.

The issue should be fixed after that.

I am fairly confident it is the [**"RebuildDescendants" part of the cleanup**](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/3422/104) that fixes the issue by rebuilding child-parent relationships between items.

A similar problem is described here:

https://weblogs.asp.net/jonelrienton/sitecore-fast-query-not-returning-items-when-searching-for-item-names-issue-and-how-to-fix

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. And what do you think was triggering this behavior? I checked this question: http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3419/how-does-the-clean-up-databases-feature-work to understand what exactly was done and couldn't understand for sure what in the list of actions has remedied the situation.

Comment: @elellle I had this happen to me before, and "Clean up Databases" always helped. I am pretty sure it's the "RebuildDescendants" task that fixes child-parent relationships in such cases.